# centered text in data-sentence HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I can't do the task: center the text from the data-sentence attribute 
After hovering over the picture (centered horizontally): https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/1/

```
[data-sentence] {
  position: relative;
}

[data-sentence]::after {
  content: attr(data-sentence);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 17px;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 55px);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 245px;
  min-height: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

[data-sentence]:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

[data-sentence='']::after {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle seems to do what it's supposed to. There is some discord across the browsers, but the text is centered in all of them. What goes wrong exactly?

Comment: it is not centered vertically and horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution with flex-box. Hope this helps. New https://jsfiddle.net/m59azhn8/2/

```
<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="./css/all.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/all.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.characters {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}

input#checkbox_yoda + label {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/fqqbDn/yoda.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
}

input#checkbox_trooper + label {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/jBdk67/trooper.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
}

input#checkbox_vader + label {
  background: url("https://image.ibb.co/chLbDn/vader.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display:inline-block;
}

label[for=checkbox_yoda] {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: transparent;
}

label[for=checkbox_trooper] {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: transparent;
}

label[for=checkbox_vader] {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: transparent;
}

input:hover + label {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}

[data-sentence] {
    position: relative;
}

[data-sentence]::after {
    content: attr(data-sentence);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 17px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1000;
    display:none;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;

    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% - 55px);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 245px;
    min-height: 50px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

[data-sentence]:hover::after {
    display: flex;
}

[data-sentence='']::after {
    display: none !important;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="characters">
    <form action="#" method="get">
      <input type="hidden" name="v" value="dQw4w9WgXcQ">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input id="checkbox_yoda" type="checkbox" name="character" value="light_side">
          <label for="checkbox_yoda" data-sentence="Force is strong in you">Yoda</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="checkbox_trooper" type="checkbox" name="character" value="dark_side">
          <label for="checkbox_trooper" data-sentence="Just chillin'">Trooper</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input id="checkbox_vader" type="checkbox" name="character" value="dark_side">
          <label for="checkbox_vader" data-sentence="There is no escape from the Dark Side.">Vader</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="submit">Turn to the dark side</button>
    </form>

  </section>
</body>

</html>
```